# Handling multiple "when" statements

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

During my Modelica simulation, I have a scenario where I need to record the value of a variable at specific times using multiple when statements. The current approach involves writing individual when statements for each recording time, which becomes cumbersome when dealing with a large number of recording times.

```
model RecordVariables
  Real x[3];
  Real y;

initial equation 
  y = 11;

equation 
  der(y) = -y;

  when time >= 0.1 then
    x[1] = y;
  end when;

  when time >= 0.2 then
    x[2] = y;
  end when;

  when time >= 0.3 then
    x[3] = y;
  end when;
end RecordVariables;
```

This approach works, but it's not very scalable, especially when dealing with hundreds of recording times. Is there a more efficient way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I guess something like this would work:

```
model RecordVariables
  parameter Integer N = 10;
  Real x[N](each start=0);
  Real y;

initial equation 
  y = 11;
equation 
  der(y) = -y;
  for i in 1:N loop
    when sample(0, 0.1*i) then
      x[i] = y;
    end when;
  end for;
end RecordVariables;
```

Comment: It should be `when time>=0.1*i then` to preserve the logic of the original model. (Using sample would be better, but require more complicated logic.)

Comment: Yes, that is true. I assumed sample was intended. They can adapt the code rather easy.